# AWS Jupyter notebook can't find runnable browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

So I'm trying to run an AWS powered jupyter notebook. "The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 20:41:45.554 NotebookApp] https://localhost:8888/ No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.' is what it's telling me. It doesn't work when I copy the local address into my browser. I had no other notebooks open at the time, but I'm able to open a local (non-AWS) notebook without a problem.

Comment: Where do you see the message "no web browser found"

Comment: You can ignore that message "No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser". It just means, there server do not have a browser installed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow port 8888 on the ec2 security group. There is a similar question posted. See if you have followed the steps correctly.

[ssh AWS, Jupyter Notebook not showing up on web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570038/ssh-aws-jupyter-notebook-not-showing-up-on-web-browser)